# Can I find out when I earned a specific privilege?

Tags: support, privileges

I have recently earned the *Cast close and reopen votes* privilege when I crossed 3000 reputation. Now I wanted to find out when I earned the *Edit Questions And Answers* privilege.

Is it possible to know the date? It is not displayed when I hover on the [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges?tab=all) link.

Comment: Privilege can be earned or lost, so tracking them increases the burden on the system without any positive effect. If you want to, you can take a look at the `/reputation` page to look at the reputation changes and the total reputation at the end of each day where you have reputation changes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may go to your [Stack Exchange Network Profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/3318693/san-krish?tab=reputation) and hover on the reputation graph, which will show your reputation points and date.

According to your graph, you got 'Edit Questions and Answers' privilege on Aug 12 when you crossed 2000 reps.

> [image]

Comment: That same point in the graph is Monday August 11 for me.

Comment: @Scimonster I guess the graph is not showing UTC timezone

Answer (score 5):

[Aziz Shaikh's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275463) works well, but it won't show anything for sites where you don't have 200 rep. You can go to http://SEsite.com/reputation (example: https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) for a textual reputation of such a graph. You have to be logged in on this site.

Comment: Can you elaborate it on how to get the  _a textual reputation of such a graph_ ? . as the link redirects to the salesforce website

Comment: exchange `SEsite.com` for any SE site where you're currently logged in.